# Recreating Google Sheets functionality

Tags: python, printing, google-sheets

I just need pointers on where to begin. I have some experience with Python, but nothing to brag about.

My end goal is to create a website that will allow multiple users to access it from different computers to fill the table with simple data, very simillar to what Google Sheets alows, and then printing it on a single sheet of paper. Idealy I want my programm to intelegently determine the width of rows and columns so that the table would look decently and would fill the page accordingly.

Right now all I need is some pointers on where to begin. Like can I use SQL to create these tables and have online fuctionality for users to access and fill the spreadsheet, and how to go about printing it.

I know this is very noob question, but I can't seem to find anything relevant here on by just using google.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a very good StackOverflow question because it is very broad and not programming specific. You are asking how to start a new software project which in my opinion belongs more in the software engineering meta: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Anyhow, how I would take on such a project:

1. First I would define my project scope. What is the functionality of the end-product? What must it be able to do and what not? Who are the end-users using the product and what do they expect? These are so called functional requirements.
2. In which way does the product deliver value? Is it fast, modifiable, distributed... These are so called non-functional requirements.
3. Develop a basic software architecture based on the previous requirements using patterns and tactics and identify the different subsystems. On the top of my hat I would divide it in a frontend component using a web application, backend component in your favourite language and a database component for persistence.
4. Research possible languages frameworks for each component, decide and start coding!

For the 4th step I suggest you have a look at Python Django which includes all of this stuff out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that there is software engeneering stackexchange. As for project, I do have some answers for these questions, I just had a roadblock in terms of printing fuctionality. I am planning on building backend by myself, and then using external help on front end.  Anyway, thank you again for you answer.